# Как разослать сообщения в телеграм боте, имея базу user_id (telebot+sqlite)

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Сижу над этим вопросом 2 вечера, не могу понять что надо делать: есть база с id юзеров, как сделать так чтобы по команде в боте осуществлялась рассылка по всем id? Видел похожий вопрос, но он мне никак не помог, к сожалению.

вот отправка на 1 id:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['dist'])
def dist(message):
    bot.send_message(11111111, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Как сделать отправку по id в базе?

Comment: Что нужно писать после message_to_send я не сильно понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно таки простой вопрос - вам поможет цикл `for` :)

Допустим ваша таблица в `sqlite` называется - `orders`.

Простой пример:

```
def connecting():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    return conn


@bot.message_handler(commands=['dist'])
def dist(message):
   conn = connecting()
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM orders")
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for result in results:
       bot.send_message(result[0], message_to_send) # в message_to_send передайте текст любым удобным для вас способом
   conn.close()
```

Comment: `bot.send_message(int(''.join(result)), message.text[message.text.find(' '):])

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`  что должно быть в " ".join?

Comment: @dist,  отредактировал полноценный ответ. Теперь в структуре БД ничего менять не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, добавил только конструкцию try-except чтобы бот не падал если юзер его заблокировал